# Getting raster file of SoilGrids into ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, soilgrids

The instructions to download raster soil maps is to "fetch the files `cfvo_5-15cm_Q05.vrt` and `cfvo_5-15cm_Q05.ovr` plus the `cfvo_5-15cm_Q05` folder". I can easily download the .vrt and the .ovr but I do not know how to 'fetch' the hundreds of individual .tif files in the folder and subfolders containing them.

I am an economist not a GIS expert.

These are the files I need to 'fetch', including in each subfile: https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/nitrogen/nitrogen_0-5cm_Q0.05/

Comment: Try typing "bulk download links in browser" into Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Windows network drive (Webdav), as indicated [here](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/soilgrids-access), and copy the content to your computer, or use the WCS service functionality on ArcGIS Pro  [here](https://www.isric.org/instruction-wms)